# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 14 column 34 (char 316), with JSON and discord.py

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a simple command on my discord.py bot that loads in a json file and edits it, but when I run the command, it gives me this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 14 column 34 (char 316)
```

for this line of code:

```py
with open('servers.json', 'r+') as f:
        jsonservs = json.loads(f.read())
```

the `jsonservs = json.loads(f.read())` line.
But when I run that line in another non-discord.py file, it works fine.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance if you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the error message, It seems like there is an invalid syntax in the json file. Check that and try and fix it, then see if it works.

yes, I post questions too quickly.